# Java Script Function Not Returning Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a java script function that return a string value, when i call this function on button click it return nothing.

Here is my function code:

```
function PlotMap(StartLat, StartLog, EndLat, EndLog) {

var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var llList = "";

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: StartLat, lng: StartLog },
        zoom: 15
    });


    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();

} //End function initMap


function calcRoute() {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(StartLat, StartLog);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(EndLat, EndLog);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    bounds.extend(start);
    bounds.extend(end);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
                var routes = response.routes;
                for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
                    var points = routes[j].overview_path;
                    var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
                    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
                        ul.appendChild(li);
                        llList = llList + getLiText(points[i]) + " / ";
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Directions Request from " + start.toUrlValue(6) + " to " + end.toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
        }
    });
} //End function calcRoute

function getLiText(point) {
    var lat = point.lat(),
        lng = point.lng();
    return "lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng;
}


initMap();

return llList;}
```

And Here i am calling this function on button click in asp.net page.

```
<script>

function ii() {

    var tt = PlotMap(26.547648, 81.529472, 26.612515, 81.354248);

    alert(tt);
}</script>
```

Asp.net page code:

```
<body>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="ii();"/>
<div id="map" style="float: left; width: 70%; height: 400px;"></div>
<ul id="vertex">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Everything works fine but function not returning any value. Please help i am new in web development. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the logic in your code and it looks sound. As I was able to get it to return a sting as you wanted but had to comment out all the google map logic.

Although, I noticed, the below if statement has no else statement therefore if this statement returns false then the string will be empty and you wont be alerted.

```
if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
```

Maybe try adding a matching `else` statement:

```
} else { alert("No Routes"); }
```

This should at least give you some more insight into what is going on.

Here is the new logic in your calcRoute function:

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(StartLat, StartLog);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(EndLat, EndLog);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    bounds.extend(start);
    bounds.extend(end);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
                var routes = response.routes;
                for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
                    var points = routes[j].overview_path;
                    var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
                    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
                        ul.appendChild(li);
                        llList = llList + getLiText(points[i]) + " / ";
                    }
                }
            } else { alert("No Routes"); }
        } else {
            alert("Directions Request from " + start.toUrlValue(6) + " to " + end.toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
        }
    });
} //End function calcRoute
```